# Keras, Face Detection with only one image

Tags: python, keras, object-detection

I am new to object detection. And I can't figure out how to train a model to recognize a face in a picture. There are many mnist tutorials and pretrained model tutorials but not a case like this.

I will assign numbers to my questions.

```
folderpath = "G:/Datasets/FACE/"
face = "face.JPG"
people = "people.JPG"

maskdict = {}
nfaces = 0

image= Image.open(folderpath+face)
image = image.convert('L')
image= np.array(image)
print(image.shape) # (239, 162)
```

I turned the Face into grayscale so it would be easier to work.

```
def create_mask(image, plotimg=False):
    height, width = image.shape
    mask = np.empty((height, width))
    topcroph = int(height*0.9)
    botcroph = height-topcroph
    rightcropw = int(width*0.9)
    leftcropw = width - rightcropw

    mask[botcroph:topcroph, leftcropw:rightcropw] = 1
    img = image.copy()
    if plotimg:
        img[botcroph:topcroph, leftcropw:rightcropw] = 1
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    return mask.astype(np.uint8)
```

**Creating mask**

Assuming the input always will be a closeup face, create_mask function creates a mask very roughly where the face is, so I can use that mask as 'y' (label)

*1- Is this the correct way of creating a 'y'(label) for detection?*

```
def resizer(img, msk, size):
    img = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((size,size)))
    msk = np.array(Image.fromarray(msk).resize((size,size)))
    return img, msk
```

Resize both image and it's mask.

```
mask = create_mask(image, plotimg=True)
img, msk = resizer(image, mask, 128) # img & mask.shape would be (128,128)

img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2) # add one more dimension
msk = np.expand_dims(msk, axis=2) # (128, 128, 1)
```

**Augmentation**

In the below code, I wanted to multiply the image, so I could have a dataset.

*2- Technically, you can't train with one image, right?*

```
datasize=120
data = np.empty((datasize, 128, 128, 1))
maskage = np.empty((datasize, 128, 128, 1))
for i in range(0, 40):
    np.random.seed(i)
    img_r = keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(img, 30)
    msk_r = keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(msk, 30)
    maskage[i,:,:] = msk_r
    data[i,:,:] = img_r
for i in range(40,80):
    np.random.seed(i)
    img_b = keras.preprocessing.image.random_brightness(img, (.5, 1.5))
    maskage[i,:,:] = msk
    data[i,:,:] = img_b
for i in range(80,120):
    np.random.seed(i)
    img_z = keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(img, (.7, 1))
    msk_r = keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(msk, (.7, 1))
    data[i,:,:] = img_z
    maskage[i,:,:] = msk_r
```

**Model**

Keras model throws ValueError. I can't figure out how to configure layers, how does this work?

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding="same", input_shape=(128,128,1)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding="same"))
model.add(layers.Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()

    _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 16)      160       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 128, 128, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 16)      2320      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 128, 128, 16)      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 2,480
Trainable params: 2,480
Non-trainable params: 0

# Input shapes are:
data.shape  # (120, 128, 128, 1) 
maskage.shape  # (120, 128, 128, 1)

#Run the model
model.fit(data, maskage)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_6 to have
>   shape (128, 128, 16) but got array with shape (128, 128, 1)

*3. What should I do at this point?*

*4. Even if the model manages to train, will model.predict on "people.JPG" work?
 How can I draw a rectangle on face prediction output? Will this method work?*

Edit: Model started to train after I changed the second conv2d layer variable from 16 to 1. But It can't find the face.

Answer (score 3):

Before starting your questions let me some important thing to be more clear. As far as I understand your goal is to achieve both `classification` and `localization`. These both needs different models to be trained on and it is more advanced to start from scratch. Assuming you only need classification let me try to answer your questions.

1) y labels should be the binary for your case `face` or `background` and these should be 1D column array.

2) Yes you are right, flipping or rotating image is a good strategy to enrich your dataset.

3) This error happens because of the second argument of `model.fit(data, maskage)`, i.e **maskage**. Since your label needs to be a column, not a 128x128x1 array, this error occurs.

4) This method won't work as I explained before the questions. You are looking for both `localization` and `classification`

As far as I understand, you have checked the MNIST tutorials to modify to your problem, but first and most important thing is you should change the y labels. Further, since I have not sufficient knowledge to do how to properly localize objects, I won't be able to give much information about how you succeed the localization part of your project.

EDIT : For the ones who are not familiar with the `localization`, there is a helpful guide with Keras in the [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-bounding-box-regression-in-tensorflow-743e22d0ccb3)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insights,
1-) Why does it need to be 1D?  I know that Dense layer needs 1D but conv2d needs 2d, right?
3-) Model started working after I changed the second conv2d layer's variable from 16 to 1. I will try your way to understand the issue.
Teşekkürler,

Comment: For example let say we are in MNIST [link]https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/ . If you could just erase the model and fitting part and add `print(y_label.shape)`, you will encounter that the y_label shape is (60000, 10) i.e 10 class exists for images. It doesn't matter whether you use conv2d or not, it is simply a matrix multiplication, principle is same. That means you should enumerate your class names always.